# MySQL - SUM / COUNT and join in one statement

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have two tables that I want to join and sum and count in the same statement.

```
create table t1 (
code int(10) primary key,
Typ varchar(10) not null,
Status int(10) not null);


create table t2 (
code int(10) primary key,
Typ varchar(10) not null,
SubTyp varchar(10) not null);

insert into t1 values (1,'A',1);
insert into t1 values (2,'B',1);
insert into t1 values (3,'A',1);
insert into t1 values (4,'B',1);
insert into t1 values (5,'A',1);
insert into t1 values (6,'B',1);

insert into t2 values (1,'A','A1');
insert into t2 values (2,'A','A1');
insert into t2 values (3,'A','A2');
insert into t2 values (4,'B','B1');
insert into t2 values (5,'B','B2');
insert into t2 values (6,'B','B3');
```

From t1 I want to have the sum per Typ and from t2 the distinct count of SubTyp per Typ. The results I need to achive are as follows:

```
Sum Typ A   Sum Typ B   Count Typ A     Count Typ B Ratio A (count/sum) Ratio A (count/sum)
     3         3          2                  3        0.666666667          1
```

I can do sum and count on the same table but fail when I need to join them.

Comment: It isn't clear what these two tables represent, and you might want to comment on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to calculate the counts from both tables separately and merge them using `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT a1.count_a
     , a1.count_b
     , a2.count_a
     , a2.count_b
     , a2.count_a / a1.count_a AS ratio_a
     , a2.count_b / a1.count_b AS ratio_b
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN typ = 'A' THEN 1 END) AS count_a
         , COUNT(CASE WHEN typ = 'B' THEN 1 END) AS count_b
    FROM t1
) a1
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN typ = 'A' THEN SubTyp END) AS count_a
         , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN typ = 'B' THEN SubTyp END) AS count_b
    FROM t2
) a2
```

You might want to replace `COUNT(CASE ... THEN 1 END)` in first sub query with `SUM(CASE ... THEN status END)` depending on your definition of sum.